# How is this collection of open balls a covering of the first quadrant in the Euclidean $n$-space?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry

Let
$$ 
S \colon= \left\{ \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right) \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon \, x_1 > 0, \ldots, x_n > 0 \right\}. \tag{Definition 0}
$$
For each positive real number $\alpha$, let
$$
A_\alpha \colon= \left\{ \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right) \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i - \alpha \right)^2 } < \alpha \right\}, \tag{Definition 1}
$$
that is, $A_\alpha$ is the open $n$-ball with center $( \alpha, \ldots, \alpha ) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and radius $\alpha$. Finally, let
$$
\mathscr{A} \colon= \left\{ A_\alpha \colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha > 0 \right\}. \tag{Definition 2}
$$

Then how to show that the collection $\mathscr{A}$ covers $S$? That is, how to show that
$$
S \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha > 0} A_\alpha? \tag{0}
$$
And, can we be even so precise as to state that
$$
S = \bigcup_{\alpha > 0} A_\alpha? \tag{1} 
$$

My Attempt:

Let $\left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right)$ be an arbitrary point of $S$. Then $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ 
x_1 > 0, \ldots, x_n > 0. \tag{2} 
$$
Let us put
$$
\alpha \colon= \frac{ x_1 + \cdots + x_n}{n}. \tag{Definition 3}
$$
Then we note that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{
     \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i - \alpha \right)^2 
} 
&= 
\sqrt{ 
     \left( 
          \frac{(n-1) x_1 - x_2 \cdots - x_n}{n} 
     \right)^2 
     +  
     \left( 
          \frac{-x_1 + (n-1)x_2 - \cdots - x_n}{n}  
     \right)^2 
     + \cdots + 
     \left( 
          \frac{-x_1 - x_2 - \cdots - x_{n-1} + (n-1) x_n}{n} 
     \right)^2 
}
\end{align}

Is what I have done so far correct? If so, then how to proceed from here?

Or, is there some other way around this problem?

Comment: Your paragraph "Then we note that..." has a fatal mathjax error and is hence unreadable.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm sorry but despite trying my best, I've just failed to fix this error. I'd be really grateful if you could edit my post to fix this error for me. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I gave it a try. It looks like your last `\frac` command was missing its denominator.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. You can visualize its falsity in the case $n=3$ by noticing that $A_\alpha$ is tangent to the $xy$ plane at the point $(\alpha,\alpha,0)$ which lies on the $45^\circ$ degree line on that plane; and similarly for the $yz$ and $zx$ planes. In particular, $A_\alpha$ never comes near points that lie on the $x$-axis, on the $y$-axis, or on the $z$-axis.

With that visualization as motivation, consider the case $n=3$ and the point $P = (1,0,0)$ which lies on the boundary of $S$. Let's find a positive constant $d>0$ such that each set $A_\alpha$ stays at least distance $d$ away from the point $P$.

Given $Q = (\alpha,\alpha,\alpha)$ with $\alpha>0$ we have
$$d(P,Q) = \sqrt{3 \alpha^2 - 2\alpha + 1}
$$
Let's compare $d(P,Q)$ to the radius $\alpha$ of the ball $A_\alpha$:
$$d(P,Q) - \alpha =  \sqrt{3 \alpha^2 - 2\alpha + 1} - \alpha \equiv f(\alpha)
$$
The unique minimum value of the function $f(\alpha)$ occurs at $\alpha=2/3$ where that minimum is $f(2/3) = 1/3$. It follows that no matter what value of $\alpha>0$ we choose, the ball $A_\alpha$ never comes even within distance $d = 1/3$ of the point $P$. So for example the point $(1,.1,.1)$, whose distance from $P$ is $\sqrt{.02} < 1/3 = d$, is not contained in any ball $A_\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another perspective that may prove useful. The question of whether $\mathscr A$ covers $S$ is equivalent to asking whether for each $x \in S$, there exists an $\alpha > 0$ such that $\|x - \alpha e\| < \alpha$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm and $e$ denotes the all-ones vector $e = (1,1,\dots,1)$. This is in turn equivalent to asking whether for all $x \in S$, there exists an $\alpha > 0$ such that the function
$$
f(\alpha) = \frac 1{\alpha}\|x - \alpha e\| = \left\|\frac 1{\alpha} x - e\right\| < 1.
$$
Setting $t = 1/\alpha$, we can see that the above amounts to asking whether the distance from the open ray $R = \{tx : t > 0\}$ to the point $e$ is always strictly smaller than $1$.

For any $x \in S$, this distance can be readily computed with the help of a projection: we find that
$$
d(e,R)^2 = \|e\|^2 - \frac{(e^Tx)^2}{x^Tx} = n - \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}.
$$
By taking $x$ to be "sufficiently close" to one of the coordinate axes, the ratio ${\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2}\Big /{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)}$ can be made arbitrarily close to $1$, so that $d(e,R)$ is made arbitrarily close to $n - 1$.

In the case of $n = 2$, this upper bound is equal to $1$, which means that $\mathscr A$ does cover $S$. For $n > 2$, that is no longer the case, which means that there exist points $x \in S \setminus \bigcup \mathscr A$.

---

A potential followup question: what exactly does $U:= \bigcup \mathscr A$ look like, then? Because the membership of $x$ in $U$ depends only on the ray generated by $x$, we can conclude that $U$ is necessarily a [linear cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone). Moreover, it is easy to see that $U$ must be convex. So, the nature of $U$ can be determined by finding its intersection with the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, and more specifically the boundary of this intersection within the sphere.

The boundary of the set $U \cap S^{n-1}$ consists of those points $x \in S^{n-1}$ satisfying the equation
$$
1 = n - \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} = n - \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2}{1} \implies \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n-1.
$$
Thus, the boundary consists the intersection of $S^{(n-1)}$ with a plane, which is a circle whose axis is a line through the origin. With this, we can conclude that $U$ must be a right circular cone.

To find the angle of the cone, it suffices to find the angle between the cone's axis (namely $e$) and any point on the boundary. Since one point on the boundary of the cone is the point $b = (1,\dots,1,0)$, we find that
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{b^Te}{\|b\|\,\|e\|} = \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} = \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}.
$$